# SlideUp and Slidedown on hover menu

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, slidedown, slideup

I am having a menu which will show a  slider on `hover()`. I have written it like this

```
$(".menu2").hover(function ()
{
 $(".slider").slideDown(500);
  $(".slider").css('display','block');      
},
    function () {   
    $(".slider").slideUp(500);      
 //$('.slider').css("display","none");

});
```

This shows the slider.(I like to use `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` to look good). When I move my `cursor` to the slider it goes back to the `display:none` state. So I tried this

```
 $(".sliderHolder").hover(function ()
{
  $(".slider").css('display','block');              
},
    function () {

 $(".slider").slideUp(500);

 });

});
```

This sets my slider to `display:none` state after I move my cursor from the `menu`. Is there an easier way to do this though?

Comment: could you not use a boolean and pass it in as a data attribute? Then you can return a value that value for persistence when the function fires.

Answer (score 2):

Are you expecting like

http://jsfiddle.net/jUraw/1369/

```
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="home.html"><span>M</span>enu</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="fashion.html"><span>F</span>ashion</a></li>
                <li><a href="about-us.html"><span>A</span>bout <span>U</span>s</a></li>
                <li><a href="find-us.html"><span>F</span>ind <span>U</span>s</a></li>
                <li class="underline"><a href="http://www.bellissimafashions.com/blog/"><span>B</span>log</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>    
    </ul>


$(document).ready(function (){
    var t = null;
    $('#nav li').hover(function(){
        var that = this;
        t = setTimeout(function(){
            $('ul', that).slideDown(200);
            t = null;
        }, 300);
    }, function(){
        if (t){
            clearTimeout(t);
            t = null;
        }
        else
            $('#nav li ul').slideUp(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Excellent work vinothini I am solving a similar problem here. Instead of having ul inside the button tag it has to be like this http://jsbin.com/iroxop/2/ (The problem is whether i move somewhere from the button the menu has to be hide).